# Travelling to the UK with Article 10 on behalf of my child who is 7 years old and dependent child is possible?

Tags: uk, german-residents

I am a non-EEA national but my 7 years old child holds EEA nationality. For this reason we all 3 people of rest of my family posess Article 10 residence cards. Article 10 is very clearly mentioned on our cards.

In this case do we need a visa to travel to the UK? Some people replied YES and some said No but i am still not sure. I called UK border and immigration and paid almost 24€ for this call but got no satisfactory reply as its not a clear reply in YES or NO.

I am afraid because child is Minor but at the other hand is that we have been granted article 10 then there should be no obligations to get UK visa for a visit of one week?

Can anybody help? Maybe somebody has had such an experience?

Comment: I submitted an edit suggestion to clean up the language. You have tagged this [tag:germany] but there is nothing about Germany in the post -- can you please review and perhaps clarify if there is indeed some connection to Germany?

Comment: @sohail The criteria for entry are here https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card It’s not clear from your question what your EEA relative’s Member State of nationality is nor where they are currently residing, however I don’t think you meet the eligibility criteria https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residence_card_of_a_family_member_of_a_Union_citizen

Comment: This sounds very odd.  A child can sponsor a parent for an article 10 card normally only if the *parent* is dependent on the *child.*  Is your child really the only EEA national in your family?  Also, the identifying language of an Article 10 card doesn't include explicit mention of Article 10.  What does your card actually say?

Comment: @phoog This status probably derives from ECJ precedents like Chen, Ruiz Zambrano or Chavez-Vilchez (note that the court went much further than the directive, even finding grounds to allow parents to stay in the country of their child's citizenship).

Comment: You may want to [merge](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) your accounts ([user79804](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/79804/user79804) and [sohail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/79801/sohail)).

Answer (score 2):

I seriously doubt it. Even though you have the card, your situation does not clearly fall within the scope envisioned by the directive and the [UK guidance](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card) on how to apply it following the 2014 McCarthy case. Note that the guidance makes it plain that the UK (and its border guards) will double-check whether you qualify under (their interpretation of) EU law. In other words: having the card is not enough, they can demand evidence that you are really a spouse or parent or an EEA national, as applicable.

I suspect your situation is more akin to that of the Chen case but the UK takes a rather restrictive [view of its consequences](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/primary-carers-of-eea-minor-children-chen-cases-eun05/primary-carers-of-eea-minor-children-chen-cases-eun05). You would be covered by limited (derived) freedom of movement rights if your child had serious reasons to *reside* in the UK (like going to school there since their birth). But it seems unlikely to work for a touristic visit for your own purposes (or to move to the UK, for that matters).